# Why is the link only attached to the title and not the whole box in Elementor Post Filter Widget in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

So im using this [widget](https://www.elementpack.pro/demo/element/post-gallery) to display some posts that i have.
The issue is that the link is only attached to the TITLE of each post and not on the whole box.
You can see the widget on my [website](https://openborders.gr/)

I also tried some css (in my case those are the classes and id's) and for some reason it only works only on the elementor edit environment but no on the live website.

```
#bdt-post-gallery774308a .bdt-gallery-item  {
  position: relative;
}

#bdt-post-gallery774308a .bdt-gallery-item a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your custom JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".bdt-post-gallery .bdt-gallery-item").each(function() {
    var url = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
    jQuery(this).on("click", function() {
      window.open(url, "_self");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That pretty much worked! Thank you and sorry for the late reply!
I also changed the cursor to pointer for the whole box and now its perfect.